# Zeroclipboard problem

Tags: javascript, html, zeroclipboard

i run use a javascript code for getting browser information it run fine on microsoft windows xp but it not working on microsoft windows server 2003. my code is folowing. plz help.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function F() {
                var today = new Date();
                var the_date = new Date("December 31, 2012");
                var the_cookie_date = the_date.toGMTString();
                var the_cookie =  screen.width +"x"+ screen.height;
                var the_cookie = "Screen Resolution:"+the_cookie + ";\nExpires:" + the_cookie_date+";\n Browser CodeName:"+navigator.appCodeName+";\n Browser Name: " + navigator.appName+";\n Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion+";\n Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion+"; \n Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled +";\n Platform: " + navigator.platform+";\n User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent;
                /

                document.getElementById('box-content').value=the_cookie;
            }





        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="10" cols="70">
</textarea>
<br /><br />
<p><input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy to Clipboard"  /></p>

    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        //set path

        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://192.168.101.135:471/browserinfo/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf');
        //create client
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        //event
        clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
            clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
        });
        clip.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
            alert('text is copied');
        });
        //glue it to the button
        clip.glue('copy');
    </script>
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What error messages come up?

Comment: I know it works, but it gives me the willies whenever I see `<script>` blocks dropped *after* the close of the `<html>` container.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have Flash player installed on the Windows Server box, which is required to run ZeroClipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Or you don't have Flash (as said before) or you don't have access to 192.168.101.135 on servers machine....